# Is there fusion drive style solution there for Linux and Windows?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, operating-systems, cache

Is there fusion drive style (like in iMac where the SSD acts as storage space rather than cache) solution there for Linux and Windows?

Comment: Seagate has such a product.  Its their SSDD product line.  Of course I would argue that the Fusion drive also uses the SSD as a cache drive ( in other words there is nothing special about it ).

Answer (score 3):

Fusion doesn't use the SSD as a cache. Data on the SSD is not mirrored on the HD, and in that respect it is entirely *unlike* Windows ReadyBoost, Seagate's hybrid drives, and other caching systems. It's tiered storage with automatic migration.

The closest thing to that on Linux is [ZFS tiered storage with L2ARC](http://www.anandtech.com/show/3963/zfs-building-testing-and-benchmarking/2). [ZFS](http://zfsonlinux.org) is now officially supported on Linux, though still not as well as it is on BSD or Solaris/OpenIndiana. [OpenZFS](http://open-zfs.org/wiki/Main_Page) is a new project that's intended to tidy up much of the mess that has surrounded multi-platform ZFS solutions in the past.

There is also [TIER](http://www.lessfs.com/wordpress/?p=776), which aims to do the same thing in a more generic way.

There are some other alternatives discussed in [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/44026/home-brew-automatic-tiered-storage-solutions-with-linux-memory-ssd-hdd).