# Merge two physical drives into one logical and automatically move frequently used files

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, m.2

Hello Ive got a question regarding my drives,

Ive just bought a M.2 drive (PCIe) and now I want to merge this quite fast drive with my hdd. My goal is to configure them like that so that the os can move frequently used files (e.g. games) to the m.2 and leave the less used files on the hdd. Is this possible with only 2 physical drives or do I need a third for the os itself? And if possible how?

My hardware is the following:

- Mainboard: Asrock B450 Pro4
- CPU: Ryzen 7 2700X
- M.2: Patriot Viper VPN100 512GB
- HDD: Seagate Desktop SSHD 2TB
- OS: Windows 10 Pro

Thanks for your help!

Comment: This a solution looking for a problem. With your hardware I know you're not talking about enterprise loads, and so you won't get any real benefit from doing it on a personal computer. Such a system introduces huge amounts of complexity and adds resource usage for identifying and moving the files. You'd lose more resources than any gained. So don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly… I wouldn't.

Apple had Fusion drives, tied hard to the motherboards & OS, as a stop-gap until large SSDs became affordable.

Windows' equivalent, of 'tiered storage' also needed motherboard support, but wasn't as neatly tied into the OS itself.

Now SSDs are cheap, don't bother.

Also see [Is there fusion drive style solution there for Linux and Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/669455/is-there-fusion-drive-style-solution-there-for-linux-and-windows)